# Fast algorithm for any(M==2)

Tags: algorithm, matrix, r

I want to find a quick way to see if a matrix *M* has at least one value that is, say, 2. In R, I would use `any(M==2)`. However, this computes first `M==2` for all values in `M`, then use `any()`. `any()` will stop at the first time a `TRUE` value is found, but that still means we computed way too many `M==2` conditions.

I thought one could find a more efficient way, computing `M==2` only as long as it is not satisfied. I tried to write a function to do this (either column-wise `check`, or on each element of `M`, `check_2`), but it is so far much slower. Any idea on how to improve this?

Results of benchmark, where the value Val is rather at the end of the matrix:

```
|expr               |mean time |
|:------------------|---------:|
|any(M == Val)      |  14.13623|
|is.element(Val, M) |  17.71230|
|check(M, Val)      |  18.20764|
|check_2(M, Val)    | 486.65347|
```

Code:

```
x <- 1:10^6
M <- matrix(x, ncol = 10, byrow=TRUE)

Val <- 50000


check <- function(x, Val) {
  i <- 1
  cond <- FALSE
  while(!cond & i <= ncol(x)) {
    cond <- any(M[,i]==Val)
    i <- i +1
  }
  cond
}

check_2 <- function(x, Val) {
  x_c <- c(x)
  i <- 1
  cond <- FALSE
  while(!cond & i <= length(x_c)) {
    cond <- x_c[i]==Val
    i <- i +1
  }
  cond
}


check_2(x=M, Val)
check(M, Val)

library(microbenchmark)


comp <- microbenchmark(any(M == Val),
               is.element(Val, M),
               check(M, Val),
               check_2(M, Val),
               times = 20)


comp
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect any performance gains for `check()` if your `Val` is found in the last column. But it makes a different, for example, with `Val <- 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`any` is a primitive, it doesn't loop in `R` but in `C`, which is much much faster.

loops in `R` are quite slow, that's why it's important that you use said vectorized functions if you care about speed (apply functions are still loops however).

A way to speed things up is to use package `Rcpp` to write code in `C++` through R, when you have a slow `R` function that uses simple loops it's the way to go, it's still not as fast as `C` but in our case maybe that'll be enough given we don't need to go through all the vector ?

Let's check:

```
# defines anyx_cpp
cppFunction(
  'bool anyx_cpp(const NumericVector x,const double y) {
     const double n = x.size();
     for (double i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       if (x(i) == y) {
         return(true);
       }
     }
  return false;
  }')

anyx_r <- function(x,y){
  for(x_ in x) if(x_ == y) return(TRUE)
  FALSE
}    

vec <- 1:1e7
x <- 5e6
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rloop  = anyx_r(vec,x),
  cpp    = anyx_cpp(vec,x),
  native = any(vec==x)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#   rloop 166.5758 171.34355 203.15277 179.9776 198.8560 990.1650   100
#     cpp  39.5462  40.60585  57.84617  41.4594  46.1232 690.1746   100
#  native  36.9900  37.86090  51.80317  38.9640  43.6510 888.3059   100
```

Almost but not quite ;).

So bottom line, in general you can trust vectorized R functions, even if it might seem they're working too much at first sight.

Comment: great answer, thanks a lot for the good work!